# Templated function with optional compile time arg

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, optional-parameters, compile-time

I have the following templated functions with an optional `port` argument, which should be recognized at compile time:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void inner(T arg1){...}

template<typename T>
void inner(T arg1, int port){...}
```

I want to call the inner functions from outer functions with minimum repetition:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void outer(T arg1){
    /* Do some stuff */
    inner(arg1);
}

template<typename T>
void outer(T arg1, int port){
    /* Do same stuff as in void outer(T arg1) */
    inner(arg1, port);
}
```

In my solution attempt I made use of variadic templates:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void outer(T arg1, Args... args){
    inner(arg1, args...);
}
```

It is used like this:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    outer(10);
    outer(10, 20);
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, I do not like to have a variable amount of parameters but just 0 or 1.
Either you specify the port or not.
How can I do this?

Tried to explore `SFINAE`, `enable_if` and such, but I was not able to make sense out of it.

Comment: *"do not like to have a variable amount of parameters"* Why not? You get a compilation error for >1 argument either way. Also, you should be using `std::forward` and forwarding references in `outer` to avoid extra copies.

Comment: You could always add a helper function with a variable number of parameters and "hide" it in some namespace `namespace impl { template<class T, class...Args> void outer_helper(T&&t, Args&&...args) { ... ::inner(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Args>(args)...); } } template<class T> void outer(T t) { impl::outer_helper(std::move(t)); } ...`

Comment: Why not just make the parameter a `std::optional<int>`? With a default value of `std::nullopt`, of course.

Comment: @fabian I like when the functions do what they promise. However, a function taking ` Args... args` would make the user think it accepts from 0 to 100 (or more) port arguments, where actually there are only 0 and 1 port arguments. 0, if port is irrelevant and 1 if port is relevant. Although 0 or 1 ports is of course a special case of a variable amount of port arguments.

Comment: That's why my suggestion is to use an internal function for avoiding the duplication of logic that is not supposed to be used by the user of your API. The user would be using 2 overloads of `outer` that both call `impl::outer_helper(...)`. If instead of calling `inner(x)` you could also be calling `inner(x, k)` for some constant `k`, the solution actually is much simpler: just add a default value for the function parameter...

Comment: write a function and move `/* Do some stuff */` inside the function

Comment: BTW, `outer` might be simplified (and resmble even more to a forwarder) to `template<typename... Args> void outer(Args... args){ inner(args...); }`. Pack size would be 1 or 2 instead of 0 or 1.

Comment: https://ideone.com/k8UyNI Just make the port argument have a default value.

Comment: @Brandon: That would give me many unused port argument warnings for those overloads of inner which do not use port.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: Actually I would need to call two helper functions: `before_inner(...)` and `after_inner(...)`. However, that would be possible.

Comment: @avans The overloads of `inner` that do not use `port` do not have the parameter in the first place, why would that give you a warning?

Comment: Because, when I give the `inner` overloads a default port argument `port = 0`, which I then do not use, as suggested by @Brandon, the compiler will remind me about that.

Comment: @avans; Huh? `inner` will use the port if `!= default value`. If not, it's fine. You can also mark it with `[[maybe_unused]]` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused or whatever the compiler specific flags are. I don't actually see why it would be unused at all, since one `inner` function would handle everything with the port. If the port is default, then just do the regular code without it. So in one branch it'll always be used.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to avoid repetition is to write a function:

```
void Do_some_stuff(Some args);

template<typename T>
void outer(T arg1){
    Do_some_stuff( ... );
    inner(arg1);
}

template<typename T>
void outer(T arg1, int port){
    Do_some_stuff( ... );
    inner(arg1, port);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options to consider. The easiest one is using a variadic template but limiting the number of arguments in the outer function, e.g. using static_assert

```cpp
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
void inner(T arg1){std::cout << "one\n";}

template<typename T>
void inner(T arg1, int port){std::cout << "two\n";}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void outer(T arg1, Args... args){
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) < 2, "no more than one param");
    inner(arg1, args...);
}


int main()
{
    outer(1,2);
    outer(1);
//    outer(1,2,3); //fails to compile
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ehcej8zrs

Given the type of the second parameter is known, `outer` can be a single function taking two parameters, one of which is an optional empty by default. I cannot tell if it's acceptable from your API and ABI's standpoint, if it is though, it looks more-less the following way:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

template<typename T>
void inner(T arg1){std::cout << "one\n";}

template<typename T>
void inner(T arg1, int port){std::cout << "two\n";}

template<typename T>
void outer(T arg1, std::optional<int> port = {} ){
    if (port) {
        inner(arg1, *port);
    } else {
        inner(arg1);
    }
}


int main()
{
    outer(1,2);
    outer(1);
//    outer(1,2,3); //fails to compile
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6jnnMMGKW

For the sake of the example I have assumed you are using C++17 or newer, if not, `std::optional` can be replaced by the one from Boost.